# Z690 pro wifi ddr4, iwlwifi failed with error -2

Tags: linux

When I do

sudo dmesg | grow iwlwifi

I get the errorDirect firmware load for iwlwifi failed with error -2.

Looks like my firmware for motherboard Wi-Fi is not up to date. When I
git pull
the link posted below I just get Already Up to Date

Something is wrong, I am using Hive os for crypto mining

Somebody smart help me out

WiFi not working